# facebook integration problem in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

HI..

i want to implement facebook in my iphone game .. i want when game is over there is a facebook connect button .. using which a player can share his score on his wall in facebook .. i have follow the way which is describe in this video { http://vimeo.com/3616452
 }
but i am getting session not declare error ..
so please help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This video is rather old. They use old facebook-iphone-sdk that is still working but Facebook recommend using new iOS SDK https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

It's a lot easier now. You can find sample project there and adopt it to you app.

I think you getting "session not declare" error because you didn't include facebook sdk header files in your project or Xcode couldn't find it if you SDK placed in another directory.

If you show us some code and better describe your problem it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: @sergnsk 
thanks alot i ll try and then let u knw .. thanks once again

Comment: dear i have follow this 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios
when i start my app its direct me to fb login n after login its not redirecting me... i just want to share score on user wall .. help neeeded

Comment: to redirect back in your app you need implemeting three things - 1.
set up you appid in code 2. set up your appid in your app configuration plist as mention in help - fb[yourappnumber] 3. and!!!
in *AppDelegate.m implement this method 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
  return [[controller facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}

Comment: @sergnsk

thanks for being kind... actually i want when game end then i give a option to player either he want to share or not if he is interested in share his score then he login and  his score ll share .. hope u getting my point

Comment: yes I totaly get you point ))) you can do it. First of all you need to login to FB successfully and return to you app after that .Can you achieve this as I describe above? you can write me e-mail to s.sojik at google.com